# Solving a series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)}}$$
Wolframalpha said its value is $2\log(2) -\log^2(2)$.

I suspect the series $\log(2)=1-1/2+1/3-1/4+...$ may be related to this series. But I'm stuck from here.

Comment: @Khosrotash How does rewriting the series constitute a "HINT?"

Comment: Hem, where is the series ?

Comment: You deleted crucial parts of the question when editing, please don't do that. I reverted the edit. If you wish to improve the question feel free to edit as long as you don't change the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ we have $\frac{-\log(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 1} H_n x^n $ and

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}H_n\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)= \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1} H_n\left(x^{2n-2}-x^{2n-1}\right)\,dx $$
equals:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log(1-x^2)}{x^2(1+x)}\,dx. $$
The last integral can be computed by exploiting the reflection formula for the [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) function.

Comment: Aw pooey, I was just trying this approach myself :-P